# Download multiple images from firebase storage one by one

Tags: java, android, callback, firebase-storage

I'm writing a function that downloads multiple images from firebase storage

here's the code:

```
public static void downloadImage(String imgName, final OnBytesSuccessListener listener) {

  StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        .getReferenceFromUrl("gs://xxxxxx.appspot.com/images").child(imgName + ".png");

  final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

  storageRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
      if (bytes == null) {
        listener.onBytesSuccess(null);
      } else {
        listener.onBytesSuccess(bytes);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

OnBytesSuccessListener is a callback function that returns bytes data, and then call the function in a loop to download all images.

But in this case, all the images will almost download at the same time. Is there any way to let them download one after the previous one download completed?

Comment: What's the problem with downloading at the same time?  It's probably faster that way.

Comment: @DougStevenson well, in some reasons, I want to show the progressbar that indicates the progress of downloading. But if they download at the same time, the progressbar then become useless

Comment: It could be useful if it tracked the status of the entire batch of downloads.

Comment: @DougStevenson something like calculates the total bytes of all images?

Comment: That's what I'd do.